# What is the quickest way to rehash?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

From Mark Weiss's Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++:

```
/**
* Rehashing for quadratic probing hash table.
*/
void rehash( )
{
    vector<HashEntry> oldArray = array;

    // Create new double-sized, empty table
    array.resize( nextPrime( 2 * oldArray.size( ) ) );
    for( auto & entry : array )
        entry.info = EMPTY;

    // Copy table over
    currentSize = 0;
    for( auto & entry : oldArray )
        if( entry.info == ACTIVE )
            insert( std::move( entry.element ) );
}
```

It seems like a really painful operation of having to go through *every* element in the table, and checking to see if the element is active or not. Particularly, is there an implementation that only means going through the number of elements inserted (as opposed to the entire table)?

Comment: A linked hash structure (where entries are connected as a doubly-linked list as well) would allow you to directly traverse the elements rather than the whole table (and allow you to iterate the table in insertion order, instead of arbitrary order). Would that work?

Comment: Would this work in a closed hashing scenario (my goal)? For reference: Open Hashing (Separate Chaining): In open hashing, keys are stored in linked lists attached to cells of a hash table.

Closed Hashing (Open Addressing): In closed hashing, all keys are stored in the hash table itself without the use of linked lists.

Comment: You only have to rehash when the number of elements inserted is at least half the size of the table, so it is not in any way expensive to check all the table cells.

Comment: Matt's right (resizing's generally triggered by a max load factor between half and 90%), and the checks are almost free given you're accessing data elements in the vicinity and it'll all be in your fastest CPU cache.  If I were you I'd be a lot more concerned by `vector<HashEntry> oldArray = array;` - this creates a deep copy of `array` unnecessarily.

Comment: If you're concerned about the overhead of calculating all the hash codes again, you can store the calculated hash code of each key with the key and re-use the stored value.  That way you only have to calculate the hash code once per key.

Comment: Some implementations do get creative... e.g. keeping the smaller `vector<HashEntry>` *and* a bigger version that's initially empty, and migrating elements across one at a time as they're handled during other operations (e.g. `insert`, `erase`, `find`), which typically requires 2 lookups instead of 1, but avoids the up-front cost of proactively rehashing.

Answer (score 0):

See Per-Ake Larson, *Dynamic Hashing,* CACM April 1988, pp 446-457. He describes a hashing system where buckets can be split and only the hashcodes for the splt bucket need recomputing.

You will find a ['C' version of it coded as an `hsearch(3)` replacement](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news095f1/b118/comp/sources/misc/00000814.html), in Usenet comp.sources.misc archives for July 1998, contributed by ejp@ausmelb.oz (me). This code has subsequently found its way into the Berkeley DB and various other places including OpenLDAP. Sorry I don't have the original source code still but I do have a Java implementation.

Comment: Aren't you using open hashing (e.g. `p = &q->Next;`)?  The question's about closed hashing (*"Rehashing for quadratic probing hash table"*) - so the techniques are quite different.